# Fiber bragg grating simulation

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

I am trying to simulate a FBG with a windows based software.
It would be great if someone suggest a proper software for me.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link for Pyhton code
https://github.com/ElsevierSoftwareX/SOFTX-D-16-00034

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of Simulation tools for FBGs including Optigrating Rsoft and COMSOL. you can use Matlab and Python if you know how to code in Matlab/Python.
as long as I know there are good equipment in Optigrating to simulate all types of FBGs including uniform FBGs, Apodized and Long period Gratings.